# python spark streaming word count in each group

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have some twitter data in Kafka and now I try to using pyspark streaming to analysis top-k word frequency in each state, the data looks like:

```
{"state": "AK", "tweet": "hello world"}
{"state": "MN", "tweet": "hello cruel world"}
{"state": "AK", "tweet": "hello cool world"}
```

The output I want to generate is:

```
"AK", "hello", 2
"AK", "world", 2
"AK", "cool", 1
"MN", "hello", 1
"MN", "world", 1
"MN", "cruel", 1
```

My code looks like this:

```
def get_word_count(line):
    tokens = get_tokens(line['tweet'])
    state = line['state']
    return [state, tokens]

dstream_tweets.flatMap(lambda line: get_word_count(line)) \
              .map(lambda line:((line[0], line[1]), 1)) \
              .reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x+y)
```

The class of `dstream_tweets` is `pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream`

This code can't calculate top-k twitter word frequency of each state in streaming data, are there some ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [this example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/stateful_network_wordcount.py) from Apache Spark Source code, you only have to change two parts:

1. Change the input to use twitter.
2. Use updateStateByKey function to make the count stateful, but instead the key is the word, you have to compose a key using (state, word).